# Sending SMS from AWS Pinpoint to Viber

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm looking for a way to send SMS from Pinpoint to Viber. Has anyone tried and implemented this before?

All suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is Viper? Can you share what you've trued so far and its not working?

Comment: Hi. Viber, the messaging application. I'm trying to use it as a Custom channel for sending messages in AWS Pinpoint instead of SMS / E-mail.